# Can I play on two different devices using the same account?

Tags: zen-koi

I have downloaded the mobile game Zen Koi for my iPhone first and played a little. I have later downloaded it for a tablet running on Android.

The game itself mentions things like

> Send a koi to your friend

in the empty ‘inbox’. The settings menu also gives me a ‘player ID’ (a long chain of letters) that can apparantly be copied and pasted somewhere. Both of these prompt me to assume that ‘accounts’ exist in some way. However, I have been unable to find any ‘link accounts’ feature.

Since I have already made considerable progress on my iPhone version of the game, I would love to connect the Android version to the former. Is there any way of doing it?

Note: The game does provide a ‘support forum’ link — but that leads me to a Facebook page which is useless for me. (I am not on Facebook.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the FAQ on their Facebook page but as you do not have Facebook I have copied it for you:

> #### Can I play on different devices and have the progress of each game linked?
>
> Zen Koi do not have syncing feature, even if you have Facebook connect ON, it only helps save the progress. When you play on another device, your progress will not be linked even if you have Facebook connect ON.

[Zen Koi FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/notes/zen-koi/frequently-asked-questions/1686356868311368/)

Comment: Can you link to their facebook page from which you pulled this quote?

Comment: ok of course *** https://www.facebook.com/notes/zen-koi/frequently-asked-questions/1686356868311368/***